ARM64 link failure, unresolved external symbol
I am trying to Compile a Driver Project for arm64. The Build fails at Link Step due to 2 missing symbols - __security_pop_cookie and __security_push_cookie, however for x86 and x64 build and link works fine.
Error Trace-
1>wdmsec.lib(ppregstate.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_pop_cookie
1>wdmsec.lib(cmregutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_pop_cookie 1>wdmsec.lib(ppregstate.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_push_cookie 1>wdmsec.lib(cmregutil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __security_push_cookie
Fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
I am trying to compile a driver project for ARM architecture, I set the support for ARM in .Vcxproj file for ARM, I was expecting the project to get build for ARM as project is able to get build for x86 and x64.
